# Discovered Gap Between Extension and Parapet Wall

Tags: exterior, gap, extension

I have a rowhome that has an extension in the back. I noticed through some holes in the drywall that there is a noticeable gap between where the extension and the (shared) brick wall of my neighbor should meet. These are exterior walls, so I am a little worried. How concerning should this be? And what is the best material/technique to appropriately patch this?

Thank you,

Comment: It would be normal to have a air gap

Comment: I may not be explaining it correctly. I can work my pinky between my extension and the brick to the outside air. that doesn't seem like it should happen. should it?

Comment: Could you please add a photo? It might help visualize the issue.

Comment: Pinky size might just be to give space to make the wall straight and plumb, the other wall(brick) not perfect.  There are other reasons also.  It should be sealed on the outside so wind/rain does not blow though it